# Converting mp4 to mp3 with ffmpeg fails with: Unable to find a suitable output format for '\ffmpeg'

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, mp4

I want to convert a church service mp4 video into a mp3 soundtrack.

I found `ffmpeg` and I tried a lot of syntax. Even the easiest didin't work.

```
ffmpeg -i 2026857739212839680.mp4 output_file.mp3
```

From other articels I found that this should be the most best match to what I want to do.
But again the failure.

What am I doing wrong?

```
ffmpeg -i 2026857739212839680.mp4 -vn -b:a 128k -c:a libmp3lame output_file.mp3
```

Here the output:

```
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2026857739212839680.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
      Duration: 00:22:18.94, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2916 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 2849 kb/s, 29.76 fps, 29.85 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : VSH264 stream handler
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 63 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : AAC stream handler
      [NULL @ 000002ad5c2b00c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '\ffmpeg'
\ffmpeg: Invalid argument
```

Comment: most likely the invalid argument is -i, similar question>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/712207/ffmpeg-and-the-unable-to-find-suitable-output-error

Comment: Why is -i weong. And I can't see an answer in the given link. Also I already read this

Comment: Are you running the command in code or script, or in command-line interface?

Comment: From the command line. I start the ffmpeg with the full path... but I also tried to stay in the ffmpeg dir and give full pathes for the files to convert.